# Video Uploading with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I've searched everywhere to find an effective solution for my users of my app to upload videos from youtube, vimeo, and their pc to my rails site, given i'm a rails noob doesn't help but a point in the right direction would be swell, cheers.

Comment: You need to specify how you want to go about doing that. So do you want them to upload the video itself? or you want to store the urls of these videos?

Comment: oh ok, i want them to upload the actual videos, so they, and the public can view these videos :-)

Comment: From their PC is easy, use normal file upload. For YouTube, Vimeo, etc I'd check an open source YouTube downloader, with the caveat that it probably violates YouTube's TOS and your app's IP might be blacklisted.

Comment: Also note that if the users upload their own videos you will be facing many problems with the encoding of these videos if you want to display them like youtube, there are services like transloted that help with that area

Comment: I feel the question's digressed a little, ok, forget youtube layout and vimeo and what not, how bout just a video they have created by themselves, adn maybe an embedding of youtube and vimeo, i;'m sure they allow that

Comment: Embedding videos is discussed on the respective site's documentation. Uploading a video is a normal file upload.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For people uploading videos, you should work backwards from your player:  if you want people to view them on iPad/iPhone for example then you should use mp4 as your standard format, then they can use the native video player on those platforms.  There are lots of free javascript-based mp4 players for regular computer users too, have a google and try a couple.

So, the next problem is "how to convert videos to mp4 format" (assuming you don't want to force all users to convert to mp4 before uploading).  I would recommend Handbrake CLI for this, or ffmpeg.  Conversion is a slow process, so you don't want web requests hanging around waiting for it:  you'll need to save the uploaded file, and then either A) kick off a background job with eg Resque to convert it, or have a scheduled conversion script which runs once an hour (for example), that looks for unconverted videos, converts them to mp4, and saves the result in the appropriate place, somewhere in your "public" folder.

To handle the file uploading, you could use something like Paperclip - this will give you all of the bits and pieces to easily handle file uploading and saving to your file system.

For people who do actually want to upload youtube videos, then you have a much simpler (but seperate) task to the above.  All you need to save is the youtube url (actually just the youtube id, which is the string of digits saved in the "v" param on youtube) in your database, then you can use a standard youtube embed iframe to show the video on your site.

Comment: BTW, if you're using a shared server (including Heroku), then kicking off video conversion processes might be a problem: it might be killed for taking up too much of the system resources.  (i fell foul of this deploying my degree project, it was a proper OH F*CK moment).

Answer (score 1):

Video uploads (you can see demo [here](http://hpvideos.herokuapp.com)) are relatively simple on Rails thanks to the [Paperclip gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)

Here's a [great Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip) on how to use this:

[image]

---

**Code**

To give you some working code, here's what we used in the HPVideos app:

```
#GemFile
gem 'paperclip-ffmpeg', '~> 1.0.0'

#app/models/attachment.rb
Class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :attachment,
          styles: lambda { |a| a.instance.is_image? ? {:small => "x200>", :medium => "x300>", :large => "x400>"}  : {:thumb => { :geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10}, :medium => { :geometry => "300x300#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10}}},
          :processors => lambda { |a| a.is_video? ? [ :ffmpeg ] : [ :thumbnail ] }
    validates_attachment_content_type :video, content_type: /\Avideo\/.*\Z/ 
end

#app/controllers/attachments_controller.rb
Class Attachment < ActionController::Base
   def new
       @attachment = Attachment.new
   end

   def create
       @attachment = Attachment.new(attachment_params)
       @attachment.save
   end

   private
   def attachment_params
       params.require(:attachment).permit(:attachment)
   end
end
```

This will allow you to upload videos to your app. Remember to perform the ActiveRecord migration to enable the attachment store in your db

Comment: Ah, i didn't know that Paperclip could easily handle the conversion as well.  Will it do that asynchronously?  Can it be told to convert everything to mp4?

Comment: Hey buddy - Paperclip doesn't handle the processing - it's `ffmpeg`, it should do it async, but you'll have to use something like `resque` to queue it!

Comment: Yeah, when i said "handle the conversion" i meant "manage the conversion" i suppose: ie save the source file, run it through ffmpeg, save the results, etc.  I just noticed the paperclip-ffmpeg require at the top of your code - https://github.com/owahab/paperclip-ffmpeg .  Can't see anything there about asynchronous processing though, it's not clear how that gem actually helps.

Comment: ffmpeg is the processor - asynchronisity will come from manual implementation

Comment: Yeah, i get that.  It doesn't seem very useful to say that ffmpeg is the processor if you then need to manually implement the processing though.  I think i'm just being pedantic :)

Comment: You'd need to manually implement the asynchronous part of the processing - the ffpmeg will do it, but if you wanted to make it asynchronous you'll have to set that up yourself. Hope it's okay - I upvoted your answer btw

Comment: Oh thanks Rich, helpful, I've seen the rails cast, not sure why everyone points to that because its image not video, i am pedantic on this, but your answer is great mate, ah, what do you mean about the active record migration?